# Odroidu2: qemu-system-arm for Exynos4212

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, qemu, odroid

I have an "Odroid u2" board which comes with samsung manufactured SoC Exynos4212. I have tried building the custom kernel, u-boot and rootfs with the help of [hardkernel](https://github.com/hardkernel/linux).

But i want to test this image with qemu-system-arm. I have tried searching the compatibility for this SoC, but i didn't found any. I see the qemu is supporting for "Samsung SMDKC210 board (Exynos4210)".

To add, i also tried starting the image (which is compiled for ) with SMDKC210,but i got this error message and the system is not started : "smdkc210 board supports only 2 CPU cores. Ignoring smp_cpus value".

Any help, suggestions, comments are welcome.

Comment: paste your command line parameter for qemu

Comment: I have two different commands. 1. "qemu-system-arm -M smdkc210 -m 256 -kernel zImage -nographic -initrd ./initrd.img -append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/ram rdinit=linuxrc""  2. "qemu-system-arm -M smdkc210 -m 256 -kernel zImage -nographic -initrd ./initrd.img -append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/ram rdinit=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd""    Where the "smdkc210" means for "Samsung SMDKC210 board (Exynos4210)".

Comment: which defconfig r u using to build kernel?what steps u followed?

Comment: Am using "odroidu2_ubuntu_defconfig" from "https://github.com/hardkernel/linux/tree/odroid-3.0.y/arch/arm/configs" - which is the kernel meant for odroidu2. Am using the latest version of "builroot" by specifying the git repo in buildroot configuration file. The build was complete with all my u-boot.bin, zimage and RFS. Am doing all this in my Ubuntu-12.04 VM (using oracle virtualbox). Please revert if you need more info.

Comment: try this `"console=ttySAC0,115200n8 root=/dev/ram rdinit=/bin/sh rw "` in place of "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/ram rdinit=linuxrc"

Comment: Sorry. This didn't produce any output on my console, but with the same error. I feel the problem is with the type of board which i have used in "qemu", which is not supported for "Exynos4212".

Comment: for qemu try this config arch/arm/config/exynos4_defconfig

Comment: Still i face the same problem. I am using "ccache", so i suspect it could be the problem even after clean. And also i suspect the initrd image which was generated to run with "systemd" instead of init. But i have build with "busybox" enabled in buildroot. I will try again with my suspected areas. Thanks a lot for your continual support. I will revert again tomorrow with my results.

Comment: pls once update your build commands for kernel

Comment: Am not building the kernel manually. I used "buildroot" to include the kernel as well. Where i have option to provide "config" and also "git" repo.

Comment: can u paste build commands of buildroot. i need to know which config r u using .

Comment: builroot is the simple utility where i just configured the "defconfig" and the path of "tarball" and gave make. I am going to try it manually now. I will quickly update you the commands and results. To add, i feel am doing something wrong during the building stage.

Comment: ya u r doing wrong if u give defconfig  without any particular board it ll build wrong target .check here supported boards http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/configs

Comment: Try individual if u r board is not supported